# mongodb Filtering of content state associated with objectid in array

Tags: android, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to import the data through the filtering function.

I think we should probably use 'aggregate' instead of 'find'.

> The conditions for the data I want are:
>
> 1. There is A Collection and B Collection.
> 2. The 'contents' of A Collection points to the "_id" of B Collection.
> 3. The corresponding value is only fetched when the "Visibility" value of the B Collection is "true".

"A" Collection:

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("aaaaa"),
    "title" : "study list",   
    "contents" : [ ObjectId("11111"), ObjectId("22222") ]
}
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("bbbbb"),
    "title" : "study list",   
    "contents" : [ ObjectId("33333"), ObjectId("44444") ]
}
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("ccccc"),
    "title" : "study list",   
    "contents" : [ ObjectId("55555") ]
}
```

"B" Collection:

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("11111"),
    "visibility" : true
}
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("22222"),
    "visibility" : true
}
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("33333"),
    "visibility" : true
}
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("44444"),
    "visibility" : false
}
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("55555"),
    "visibility" : false
}
```

== Data Result

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("aaaaa"),
    "title" : "study list",   
    "contents" : [ ObjectId("11111"), ObjectId("22222") ]
}
```

How can I get the data I want?

Comment: Why output is `_id: ObjectId('aaa')` ? Contents of `ObjectId("bbbbb")` also contain `true`  value

Comment: Sorry, I can not speak English,
The bottom line is what I want
There is an Array in the Document, the Array has an ObjectId,
ObjectId refers to the Id of another collection (B)
Gets only if all of the referenced collection B's "Visibility" is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.collectionA.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "collectionB",
    "localField": "contents",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "data"
  }},
  { "$match": {
    "data": {
      "$not": {
        "$elemMatch": { "visibility": false }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```